# C++ template specialization for POD types in logger library

Tags: c++, templates, logging

I am rolling my own logging library. 
The idea is to have an interface class which must be derived from so that an object is able to be logged from.

```
class LoggedType
{
 public:
  virtual std::ostream &log (std::ostream &) const = 0;
};
```

Then the Log class will implement operator<< and for LoggedType use the log method. For everything else will use the normal operator<<.:

```
typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > CoutType;
typedef CoutType &(*StandardEndLine)(CoutType&);

class Log
{
 public:
  Log (std::ostream &);
  Log (const std::string &);
  ~Log ();

 private:
  std::ostream *os;
  bool file_p;

  friend Log &operator<< (Log &l, const LoggedType &t)
   {
     t.log (*l.os);
     return l;
   }
  template <typename T>
  friend Log &operator<< (Log &l, const T &t)
   {
     *l.os << t;
     return l;
   }
 friend Log &operator<< (Log &log, StandardEndLine manip)
 {
   manip (*(log.os));
   return log;
 }
};
```

I am getting errors as LoggedType classes are also being matched to the templated operator<<, when only non LoggedType classes should use that template.

How to best fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your template function to use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
friend
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<LoggedType, T>::value, Log &>::type
operator<< (Log &l, const T &t);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about SFINAE. However it doesn't actually work as GCC still complains about ambiguous operator<< overload for T = const char \*, where the candidates are the two operator<< defined. However, isn't it true that the one you suggested shouldn't be considered a candidate since const char* is not a base of LoggedType?

Comment: Whopps, I made a mistake on the condition for enable_if. Thanks.